# How to update ubuntu 12.04 through squid proxy server at my university?

Tags: 12.04, networking

I wish to update the local package index with the latest changes made in repositories and am using following command :

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

On executing this command I get several error messages such as one below :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
```

What i did to in order to try resolving this issue is the following :

Open terminal and the file

```
 /etc/bash.bashrsc

 sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

and add at the bottom of the file these 2 lines :

```
 export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port/
 export ftp_proxy=http://user:pass@host:port/
```

However it is still not working for me and am getting the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

try to edit /etc/apt/apt.conf like this

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://'proxy':'port'/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://'proxy':'port'/";
```